# Calculating the total number of possibilities in binary?

Tags: binary

How would you calculate the total number of possibilities that binary can have in one byte?

`00000000` through `11111111` = `num_of_possibilities`

Comment: lol.. it is a simple question, even then. ;)

Comment: Now, be nice, you were a beginner once too.

Comment: I'm not a beginner. I'm just having a really bad brainf***. Heh.

Comment: Everybody's a beginner.  Just not all about the same things.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The total number is 2 to the power of the number of bits.  So, eight bits has 2<sup>8</sup> possible values.

If you really mean "how to compute it", consider that each bit has two possible values.

So one bit implies 2 values.

Two bits has one set of two values of each possible value of the other bit, so

```
00
01
10
11
```

which means a total of 4 (= 2×2) values.

Three bits gives four values *twice*, or 8 (=4×2) values.  Four bits, 8×2; five bits, 16×2, and so on.

So eight bits is 2×2×2×2×2×2×2×2 or 256.

Comment: And, as a freebie, base-2 logarithms are how you go the other way and figure out how many bits you need to represent a given number of combinations.

Comment: Oh wow. I feel like such a moron right now! I was just talking to my friend telling him I was having a brainf*** and I couldn't figure this out. Well thanks anyways.

Comment: Nah, don't fret about it.  As they say, memory's the second thing to go.

Comment: What was the first? AHH I CAN'T REMEMBER!

Answer (score 3):

It is a simple question: The number of possibilities is 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n* is the number of bits.

So for 1 byte, which is 8 bits, there are 2<sup>8</sup> possibilites, 256.

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods:

- 2^n where n is the number of bits (2^8) Each bit has 2 possibilities.
- Unsigned value of all 1's + 1 (255 + 1) Count up from 0 to max value (all ones) + zero.
- Build a tree where each leaf is the sum of the values to right and left of the new value from the row above.  Possibilities is sum of row having n+1 entries. (2 ( 1 + 8 + 28 + 56 ) + 70) Each value is probability of that number of bits from 0 to n.