# What does data type range really means?

Tags: c

I have been reading some definitions on the internet that usually says that for example:
**" ...Since on most computers “int” data type is of 2 bytes, or 16 bits, it can only store 2^16 numbers..."**

and

**" ... And since 2^16=65535, it can only hold that many numbers ... "** - for unsigned int

I've also seen on some website that the maximum value that an int variable can hold is **"2,147,483,647"**. Then I've been wondering a bit hard the relation between the number **65535** and the number **2,147,483,647.**

I did some tests, and I saw that the maximum value that I can store is actually 2,147,483,647
in a int variable, so, what 65535 actually means then?

link: https://www.quora.com/The-range-of-int-data-type-Is-32768-to-32767-What-does-this-actually-mean-What-range-of-numbers-I-can-store-in-int

Comment: "I have been reading… on the internet": Links! There's **a lot of wrong things** on the internet, and generally, **nothing** makes much sense without context!

Comment: @MarcusMüller https://www.quora.com/The-range-of-int-data-type-Is-32768-to-32767-What-does-this-actually-mean-What-range-of-numbers-I-can-store-in-int

Comment: The wording here is *wrong*, it *intends* to say the right thing, but it's still wrong. 16 bit is ~30 years wrong, and the wording "can store 2¹⁶ numbers" is also wrong.

Comment: *"Since on most computers “int” data type is of 2 bytes*". Hasn't been the common case for decades.

Comment: wow, that quora link is literally full of answers that are wrong, or based on Turbo C++ – something that has been *declared dead* since 15 years. You can completely ignore anything written there, @DeepakC. Find a better source than quora!

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok, Thank you:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the history of computers, byte and word sizes have varied considerably; you don't always had a neat system of 8-bit bytes, 16-bit words, 32-bit longwords, etc.  When C was being developed in the early 1970s, you had systems with 9-bit bytes and 36-bit words, systems that weren't byte-addressed at all, word sizes in excess of 40 bits, etc.  Similarly, some systems had padding or guard bits that didn't contribute to representing the value - you could have an 18-bit type that could still only represent 2<sup>16</sup> values.  Making all word sizes powers of 2 is convenient, but it isn't required.

Because the situation was somewhat variable, the C language standard only specifies the *minimum range* of values that a type must be able to represent.  `signed char` must be able to represent *at least* the range `-127...127`, so it must be *at least* 8 bits wide.  A `short` must be able to represent *at least* the range `-32767...32767`, so it must be *at least* 16 bits wide, etc.  Also, representation of signed integers varied as well - two's complement is the most common, but you also had sign-magnitude and ones' complement representations, which encode two values for zero (positive and negative) - that's why the ranges don't go from `-2N-1 to 2N-1-1`.  The individual implementations then map those ranges onto the native word sizes provided by the hardware.

Now, it's not an accident that those particular ranges were specified - *most* hardware was already using 8-bit bytes, 16-bit words, 32-bit longwords, etc.  Many of C's abstractions (including type sizes and behavior) are based on what the hardware already provides.

`int` is somewhat special - it's only required to represent *at least* the range `-32767...32767`, but it's also commonly set to be the same as the native word size, which since the late '80s has been 32 bits on most platforms.

To see what the actual ranges are on your platform, you can look at the macros defined in `<limits.h>`.  Here's a little program I womped up to show what some of the size definitions are on my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define EXP(x) #x
#define STR(x) EXP(x)
#define DISPL(t,m) printf( "%30s = %2zu, %15s = %35s\n", "sizeof(" #t ")", sizeof(t), #m,  STR(m) )
#define DISPL2(t,m1,m2) printf( "%30s = %2zu, %15s = %35s, %15s = %35s\n", "sizeof(" #t ")", sizeof(t), #m1, STR(m1), #m2, STR(m2) )

int main( void )
{
  DISPL(char, CHAR_BIT);
  DISPL2(char, CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
  DISPL2(signed char, SCHAR_MIN, SCHAR_MAX);
  DISPL(unsigned char, UCHAR_MAX);  
  
  DISPL2(short, SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
  DISPL(unsigned short, USHRT_MAX);

  DISPL2(int, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
  DISPL(unsigned int, UINT_MAX );
  
  DISPL2(long, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX );
  DISPL(unsigned long, ULONG_MAX );

  DISPL2(long long, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX );
  DISPL(unsigned long long, ULLONG_MAX );

  return 0;
}
```

And here's the result:

```
$ ./sizes
                  sizeof(char) =  1,        CHAR_BIT =                                   8
                  sizeof(char) =  1,        CHAR_MIN =                            (-127-1),        CHAR_MAX =                                 127
           sizeof(signed char) =  1,       SCHAR_MIN =                            (-127-1),       SCHAR_MAX =                                 127
         sizeof(unsigned char) =  1,       UCHAR_MAX =                          (127*2 +1)
                 sizeof(short) =  2,        SHRT_MIN =                         (-32767 -1),        SHRT_MAX =                               32767
        sizeof(unsigned short) =  2,       USHRT_MAX =                       (32767 *2 +1)
                   sizeof(int) =  4,         INT_MIN =                    (-2147483647 -1),         INT_MAX =                          2147483647
          sizeof(unsigned int) =  4,        UINT_MAX =                (2147483647 *2U +1U)
                  sizeof(long) =  8,        LONG_MIN =         (-9223372036854775807L -1L),        LONG_MAX =                9223372036854775807L
         sizeof(unsigned long) =  8,       ULONG_MAX =     (9223372036854775807L *2UL+1UL)
             sizeof(long long) =  8,       LLONG_MIN =        (-9223372036854775807LL-1LL),       LLONG_MAX =               9223372036854775807LL
    sizeof(unsigned long long) =  8,      ULLONG_MAX =   (9223372036854775807LL*2ULL+1ULL)
```

Comment: wow, that answered every single doubt I had about this topic, thank you so much:)

Answer (score 1):

The size of an `int` is not necessarily the same on all implementations.

The C standard dictates that the range of an `int` must be at least -32767 to 32767, but it can be more.  On most systems you're likely to come in contact with, an `int` will have range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 i.e. 32-bit two's complement representation.

Answer (score 1):

16 bits can have a certain number of unique combinations (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072715/calculating-the-total-number-of-possibilities-in-binary) for an explanation of this). To figure out the number, you just need to raise 2 to the power of the number of bits. 2^16 is 65536. Since counting starts at zero, that means that 65535 is the maximum. That's for an unsigned integer though.

A signed integer uses one of the bits to determine if the number is positive or negative (this is called [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). Meaning there are only 15 bits with which to express the number. 2^15 is 32768, meaning that in the positive direction, the number can go from 0 to 32767. In the negative direction, the lowest the number can go is -32768. The total number of combinations is still 65536, but the bits just means something different in the case of a signed 16-bit integer.

With 32-bit integers, the logic is exactly the same. 2^32 is 4294967296, meaning the highest that a 32-bit number can go is 4294967295. There are exactly 2^32 combinations possible, but because it starts at zero, the highest number is exactly one less than 2^32. But if you reserve one bit for the sign, that means you can only go up to 2^31, minus one, which is 2147483648. So, using the same logic as for 16-bit numbers, we can figure out that the highest a signed 32-bit integer can go is 2147483647, and the lowest it can go is -2147483648.

As for which data types use 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits, that's platform-dependent. An `int` these days is almost always 32 bits, but that's not always been the case. If you want a data type to have a guaranteed size, you have to specifically choose one with an explicit size. In C, this can be done with the types defined in `stdint.h`. For instance, `uint32_t` would be an unsigned integer with 32 bits, meaning that on any platform, you can guarantee that the highest it can go is 4294967295.